# CentOS 6 apcupsd Trouble Shooting

Tags: centos, monitoring, troubleshooting, ups

I'm having issues with the recommended UPS monitoring software apcupsd.

It installed ok but when I run it and check the error messages it is getting spammed with all these messages and doesn't seem to be working but from the documentation it sounded as though usb setup (the ups is a usb ups) had minimal configuration needs.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for these messages?

```
  Jun  8 16:36:05 dev kernel: hiddev96,hidraw96: USB HID v1.11 Device [CTN USB UPS] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
  Jun  8 16:36:29 dev kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
  Jun  8 16:36:29 dev kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 46
  Jun  8 16:36:29 dev kernel: usb 4-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 47
  Jun  8 16:36:30 dev kernel: usb 4-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
  Jun  8 16:36:30 dev kernel: hiddev96,hidraw96: USB HID v1.11 Device [CTN USB UPS] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
  Jun  8 16:36:30 dev apcupsd[32666]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in linux-usb.c at line 609 Cannot find UPS device -- For a link to detailed USB trouble shooting information, please see <http://www.apcupsd.com/support.html>.
  Jun  8 16:36:30 dev apcupsd[32666]: apcupsd error shutdown completed
  Jun  8 16:36:31 dev kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
  Jun  8 16:36:31 dev kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 47
  Jun  8 16:36:31 dev kernel: usb 4-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 48
  Jun  8 16:36:31 dev kernel: usb 4-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
  Jun  8 16:36:31 dev kernel: hiddev96,hidraw96: USB HID v1.11 Device [CTN USB UPS] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
  Jun  8 16:36:37 dev kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
  Jun  8 16:36:37 dev kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 48
  Jun  8 16:36:37 dev kernel: usb 4-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 49
  Jun  8 16:36:37 dev kernel: usb 4-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
  Jun  8 16:36:37 dev kernel: hiddev96,hidraw96: USB HID v1.11 Device [CTN USB UPS] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
  Jun  8 16:36:52 dev kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
  Jun  8 16:36:52 dev kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 49
  Jun  8 16:36:52 dev kernel: usb 4-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 50
  Jun  8 16:36:52 dev kernel: usb 4-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
  Jun  8 16:36:52 dev kernel: hiddev96,hidraw96: USB HID v1.11 Device [CTN USB UPS] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1
  Jun  8 16:36:58 dev kernel: hub 4-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
  Jun  8 16:36:58 dev kernel: usb 4-1: USB disconnect, address 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching seems to suggest it's a hardware failure with one of the cables or the hub itself -- it actually could be hit with EMI, usually, and the hardware is forcing the port to die.

Swap out the cables, swap out a hub if that's truly in use here, and maybe verify whether anything ELSE works on that USB port/hub.  If you google, you'll find someone recommended wrapping a cable around some ferrite to smooth things out; but maybe swapping a 5$ cable for a 7$ one will make all the difference.